# R: Error: new columns would leave holes after existing columns

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, runtime-error

When running this code, I get the following error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = list(x = 0.0654882985934691,  : 
new columns would leave holes after existing columns
```

I am trying to populate a data.frame with `i` number of columns, which with the output of the posted `for` loop should look like something like this (Excel example for convenience only):

[image]

The aim is to store the output of the loop in such a way that I can get the average of each column at a later stage.

What can be done to achieve this?

```
library(plyr)
library(forecast)
library(vars)

x <- rnorm(70)
y <- rnorm(70)

dx <- cbind(x,y)
dx <- as.ts(dx)


# Forecast Accuracy
j = 12  #Forecast horizon
k = nrow(dx)-j #length of minimum training set

prediction <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:j) { 
  trainingset <- window(dx, end = k+i-1)
  testset <- window(dx, start = k+i, end = k+j)
  fit <- VAR(trainingset, p = 2)                       
  fcast <- forecast(fit, h = j-i+1)
  fcastmean <- do.call('cbind', fcast[['mean']])
  fcastmean <- as.data.frame(fcastmean)

  prediction[,i] <- rbind(fcastmean[,1])
 }
```

**Edit**

As per the comment below, I have edited the above code to specify the first variable of fcastmean.

The error I get has however changed as a result, now being:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = c(-0.316529962287372,  : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

**Edit 2**

Below is the minimum replicable version without any packages as requested in the comments. I believe that should be equivalent in terms of the question posed.

```
x <- rnorm(70)
y <- rnorm(70)

dx <- cbind(x,y)
dx <- as.ts(dx)

j = 12  
k = nrow(dx)-j 

prediction <- matrix(NA,j,j)

 for (i in 1:j) { 

  fcast <- as.matrix(1:(j-i+1))
  fcastmean <- fcast

  prediction[,i] <- (fcastmean)
}
```

Comment: fcastmean is two columns which you are trying to assign into one; also I think you mean `for (i in 1:j)` yes?

Comment: Yes @rawr, absolutely correct. Please see my edits.

Comment: 1. You should probably use a matrix and not a data.frame. 2. You should pre-allocate the data.frame to the final size instead of growing it. 3. I don't understand what `rbind(fcastmean[,1])` is supposed to achieve.

Comment: @Roland I have tried using a matrix in the past and that does make more sense to me, yet I haven't been able to add the loop output column by column (partially since each iteration gives a different length). That is when creating a matrix such as `prediction <- matrix(NA, j,j)`.

Also rbind was intended to add the results row by row, but that might well be wrong.

Comment: Each column inside a data.frame or matrix *must* be of the same length. That's why I wrote that you should pre-allocate to the final size. You can then assign to columns *and rows*.

Comment: @Roland, I see. I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure how to do that. Would it be possible to ask for an example?

Comment: If you come up with a more minimal example. I don't intend to install yet another package that I don't use myself.

Comment: @Roland Please see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your new example, try

```
sapply(1:j, function(i) `length<-`(1:(j-i+1), j))
```

The result is

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1
 [2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2     2    NA
 [3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3    NA    NA
 [4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    NA    NA    NA
 [5,]    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5   NA    NA    NA    NA
 [6,]    6    6    6    6    6    6    6   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
 [7,]    7    7    7    7    7    7   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
 [8,]    8    8    8    8    8   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
 [9,]    9    9    9    9   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
[10,]   10   10   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
[11,]   11   11   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
[12,]   12   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
```

`` `length<-`(x, j) `` pads `x` with `NA` until it reaches a length of `j`.

---

You can replace `1:(j-i+1)` with whatever function of `i` you want. In the OP's original example, I am guessing something like this will work (untested):

```
sapply(1:j, function(i){

  trainingset <- window(dx, end = k+i-1)
  # testset   <- window(dx, start = k+i, end = k+j)
  # ^ this isn't actually used...

  fit         <- VAR(trainingset, p = 2)                       
  fcast       <- forecast(fit, h = j-i+1)
  `length<-`(fcast$mean, j)

})
```

`function(i){...}` is called an anonymous function and can be written like any other.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Your example works perfectly. However, i'm still unsure as to how to apply this to the output of the `forecast` function. 

I have tried, `fcast1 <- sapply(1:j, function(i) `length<-`(fcast$mean$x, j))`, but that only populates the first column of the matrix. I realise I'm being a bit of a numpty btw so please bear with me!

Comment: @you Okay, I've edited a guess in. I haven't installed your package dependencies, so haven't tested.

Comment: Legend! that worked like a dream. Just had to specify the x variable in the last line:  `(fcast$mean$x, j)`.

Thank you!

Comment: Realised that sapply returns a list rather than a matrix (and is inconsistent depending on the data its fed, despite the data type being the same). Is there a way to make it return a matrix?

Comment: @you Yeah, I think my first edit had a way (click "edited x hours ago" below the question to see the history). I'd try `do.call(cbind, lapply(1:j, function(i) ...))`. `sapply` will "simplify to an array" as long as it sees a way to do so.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your clear help on this. Lifesaver!